# Unable to compile with GNU C++ 12 and LLVM 16 headers and libraries @ Ubuntu Focal

Tags: c++, linux, g++, openmp, llvm

I'm struggling to compile a custom OpenMP tool library on an Ubuntu system (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, focal). To compile the code I use a GNU C++ compiler v12.2.1. GNU toolchain is built from source. My custom library also requires OpenMP header (omp-tools.h) and library (libomp.*) provided by the LLVM v16.0.2. I installed LLVM from additional Ubuntu repositories.

My compilation command is:

```
g++ -O3 -fopenmp -I ~/repo/git/smcs3/stan/lib/stan_math -I ~/repo/git/smcs3/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.3 -I ~/repo/git/smcs3/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0 -shared -fPIC counter.c ompt.c -o libompt.so -lomp
```

LLVM header files are specified with an environment variable:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

However, the compilation fails returning multiple errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33,
                 from counter.h:1,
                 from counter.c:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include/stddef.h:41:39: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   41 | #if !defined(_SIZE_T) || __has_feature(modules)
      |                                       ^
```

and

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:43:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:95:3: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
   95 |   size_t __pad5;
      |   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:1:1: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<cstddef>’; did you forget to ‘#include <cstddef>’?
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
    1 | /* Copyright (C) 1991-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:98:67: error: ‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope
   98 |   char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
      |                                                                   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:98:67: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<cstddef>’; did you forget to ‘#include <cstddef>’?
```

Would you please be so kind to direct me here?

On the other hand, I can compile the same code with LLVM:

```
clang++-16 -O3 -fopenmp -I ~/repo/git/smcs3/stan/lib/stan_math -I ~/repo/git/smcs3/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.3 -I ~/repo/git/smcs3/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0 -shared -fPIC counter.c ompt.c -lomp -o libompt.so
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
```

Comment: Seems like `__has_feature` is a Clang extension that [gcc doesn't hasn't implemented](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60512)

Comment: why can't you use the Clang compiler for that?